# Help finding the limit of ln(2-x) if x tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

This is my problem. I've also put some work for the formatting!

Find the limit if it exists:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\frac{ln(2-x)}{\sqrt[3]{1-6x}}$$

I've tried solving it, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Using hospital's rule:

I know that 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-6x}} = (1-6x)^{-1/3}$$

so 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}ln(2-x)}{\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt[3]{1-6x}}$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\frac{\frac{-1}{(2-x)}}{(-1/3)*(1-6x)^{-4/3}*6}$$

After this I get really confused... I've tried stuff for hours now.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Are you sure about the limit we need to calculate? When $x\gt 2$, $\ln(2-x)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

The question says find the limit *if it exists*.

Take a look at where your function is defined. Remember, when is $\ln y$ defined?